# Selenium cannot find element from time to time

Tags: java, selenium

I use Selenium to interact with Jira. My application reads time logs from Google Sheets and inserts them into Jira time logger (non-standard Jira plugin).

The problem is that Selenium returns following exeption **from time to time** on the stage when I try to click on the TimeLog plugin (other stages work properly)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='sc-bvODop kOWqZw' and @xpath='1'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at com.fox.jiratimelog.selenium.SeleniumOperator.openTimeLog(SeleniumOperator.java:143)
    at com.fox.jiratimelog.selenium.SeleniumOperator.inputNewLogs(SeleniumOperator.java:60)
    at com.fox.jiratimelog.selenium.SeleniumOperator.runSelenium(SeleniumOperator.java:50)
    at com.fox.jiratimelog.JiraTimeLogApplication.main(JiraTimeLogApplication.java:24)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='sc-bvODop kOWqZw' and @xpath='1']"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-OFG72V5', ip: '192.168.0.105', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 86.0.4240.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:49319}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: e3a81681e9e6873351bab1211c3386e7
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@class='sc-bvODop kOWqZw' and @xpath='1']}
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    ... 4 more
```

I can run application for the first 10-15 times and it works properly, then I see such an exception.
When I close open drivers manually (via Task manager) and clean Windows and Chrome temporary files it may give me several more times to run application. Then I receive the same exception.

I tried to use different `drivers` (MS Edge), checked relative `xPath`, use different `waiting` strategies

```java
public void runSelenium(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Google")) {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

        enterLogin(driver);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        enterPassword(driver);
        Thread.sleep(7000);

        openProject(driver);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        openIssue(driver);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

// stages above work properly

        if (isNewLogsToInput()) {
            inputNewLogs(driver);
        }
    }

    private void inputNewLogs(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        int entriesNumber = reader.getEntriesNumberFromSheets();
        int numberOfNewLogs = entriesNumber - logs.getTimeLogsQuantity();
        int startPosition = entriesNumber - numberOfNewLogs;

        for (int i = startPosition; i < entriesNumber; i++) {
            openTimeLog(driver); // HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            inputTimeSpent(driver, i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            inputTimeRemaining(driver, i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            inputDateStarted(driver, i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            inputTimeStarted(driver, i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            inputWorkDescription(driver, i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            saveTime(driver);
        }
    }
```

```java
 private void openTimeLog(WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
        By.xpath("//body/div[13]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/small[1]")));
        button.click();
    }
```

[Screen with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1Up.png)

```html
<div class="sc-bIZIuE bmcBym" data-test-id="issue.views.issue-base.context.context-items.primary-items">
    <div>
        <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Time tracking</h2></div>
        <div class="sc-bvODop kOWqZw">
            <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                    <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Time tracking</span></div>
                </label></div>
                <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                    <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                        <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                            <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                    <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY">
                                        <div class="sc-eAyhxF hdkDWI">
                                            <div class="sc-kbdWBx dpBQSe"><span class="sc-kGXeez gTVGyF"
                                                                                role="presentation"><object
                                                    data="https://jira-frontend-static.prod.public.atl-paas.net/assets/stopwatch-glyph.abbc4afde0b6bdac7465517877d67af5.8.svg"
                                                    width="24" height="24" type="image/svg+xml"></object></span></div>
                                            <div class="sc-eVrGFk bqZIdq">
                                                <div class="sc-fdqjUm jBnpdo">
                                                    <div class="sc-cLmFfZ cjohbD" color="#0052CC"
                                                         width="22.669735327963174%"></div>
                                                    <div class="sc-cLmFfZ csMpYM" color="#FFAB00" width="0"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <small class="sc-iNovjJ gmkLRu" xpath="1"><span
                                                        class="sc-kyCyAI gZEfLW"><span><span class="sc-dchYKM ENMBd">2d 25m</span> logged</span></span><span
                                                        class="sc-fEVUGC eXwoSi"><span><span class="sc-dchYKM ENMBd">1w 2d</span> remaining</span></span></small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit Time tracking"
                                                type="button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Assignee</h2></div>
            <div class="sc-eZXMBi iWQVSp" data-test-id="issue.views.field.user.assignee">
                <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                    <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                        <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Assignee</span></div>
                    </label></div>
                    <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                        <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                            <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                                <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                    <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                        <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY">
                                            <div class="sc-iBlNuT fGlWRy">
                                                <div class="sc-iXKTDd ferkkY">
                                                    <div data-test-id="profilecard-next.ui.profilecard.profilecard-trigger">
                                                        <div class="sc-kiXyGy iYsZzI">
                                                            <div class="sc-ekQYnd gFYdNG">
                                                                <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; outline: 0px;">
                                                                    <span class="css-1c24z73"><span class="css-zk1cl3"
                                                                                                    role="img"
                                                                                                    aria-label=""></span></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="SingleLineTextInput__ReadView-sc-4hfvq0-0 epXzqq">
                                                                Test test
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit Assignee"
                                                    type="button"></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Labels</h2></div>
        <div>
            <div class="sc-bvODop kOWqZw">
                <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                    <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                        <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Labels</span></div>
                    </label></div>
                    <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                        <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                            <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                                <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                    <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                        <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY"><span
                                                class="sc-esExBO gIsNhp">None</span>
                                            <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit Labels"
                                                    type="button"></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Sprint</h2></div>
        <div>
            <div class="sc-bvODop kOWqZw">
                <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                    <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                        <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Sprint</span></div>
                    </label></div>
                    <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                        <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                            <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                                <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                    <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                        <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY">
                                            <div class="sc-hQDGvh fijXMI">
                                                <div class="sc-eYdvao dhbZhl"><a>FOX Sprint 1</a></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit Sprint"
                                                    type="button"></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sc-eePzDA jCyCpj">
        <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Story point estimate</h2></div>
        <div>
            <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                    <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Story point estimate</span></div>
                </label></div>
                <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                    <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                        <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                            <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                    <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY"><span
                                            class="sc-hmzhuo igqoCl">8</span>
                                        <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit"
                                                type="button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="sc-LAuEU kNfSUt"><h2 class="sc-hrBRpH juzrVt">Reporter</h2></div>
        <div class="sc-eZXMBi iWQVSp" data-test-id="issue.views.field.user.reporter">
            <div class="RootWrapper-sc-1va80k6-0 fsVJT">
                <div style="position: absolute;"><label class="Label__LabelWrapper-sc-17towfw-0 keOXhT">
                    <div class="Label__LabelInner-sc-17towfw-1 jbyPaz"><span>Reporter</span></div>
                </label></div>
                <div class="ContentWrapper-kdagst-0 fPLsyX">
                    <div class="FieldBaseWrapper-sc-14kmybr-0 cspqsP">
                        <div class="Content__ContentWrapper-ve26fj-2 feWTNh">
                            <div class="Content__ChildWrapper-ve26fj-0 ilJUcG">
                                <div class="Content-ve26fj-1 llCsQv">
                                    <div class="ReadViewContentWrapper-xymwx5-0 kLiHRY">
                                        <div class="sc-iBlNuT fGlWRy">
                                            <div class="sc-iXKTDd ferkkY">
                                                <div data-test-id="profilecard-next.ui.profilecard.profilecard-trigger">
                                                    <div class="sc-kiXyGy iYsZzI">
                                                        <div class="sc-ekQYnd gFYdNG">
                                                            <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; outline: 0px;">
                                                                <span class="css-1c24z73"><span class="css-zk1cl3"
                                                                                                role="img"
                                                                                                aria-label=""></span></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="SingleLineTextInput__ReadView-sc-4hfvq0-0 epXzqq">
                                                            Test test
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <button class="EditButton-sc-1v6bv8a-0 doKTJP" aria-label="Edit Reporter"
                                                type="button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="releases-panel-container" class="sc-jHsedM dDOmWr" data-test-id="development.releases-glance.actions">
            <div class="sc-jeZOwl eFGvoQ"><h2 class="sc-buBCPq fOTSoR">Releases</h2></div>
            <div class="sc-cPwpjd egqpOy"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three things you are doing wrong:

1. Using fixed sleeps.

This is not a good practice because for a good chunk of time your test is not doing anything. Use more flexible sleeps instead.

2. Using fragile xpath.

`//body/div[13]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/small[1]` could break easily. If you can provide the HTML of the page, we could try to find a better locator.

3. Potentially a short wait.

This `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);` is a much better approach than using `Thread.sleep()`. However, 20 seconds could be a short time, depending on the network speed, for example. Try using a longer timeout.

**EDIT:**

The problem was solved by using a CSS selector instead of XPATH selector:

```
By.cssSelector("div[class*='Content__ChildWrapper'] small")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is really useful. Unfortunately html is to big and I cannot provide it here. I'll try to find a way to fix xPaths

Comment: According to the error message, xpath is "//*[@class='sc-iNovjJ gmkLRu' and @xpath='1']". That is much better than the long xpath. Try using a longer timeout, that might help.

Comment: Is it possible I have some issues with JavaScript and I need to try some JS scripts?

Comment: Well, the error message is saying that the expected condition was not met in 20 seconds. This isn't unusual, since you are dealing with a web app that depends on network traffic, among other things. If your test is only occasionally failing, my best guess with the info at disposal is that this is a timing issue and a longer timeout could help

Comment: I tried different xPath which I can test/find in Chrome. As I see issue with timing is caused by `NoSuchElementException` which means that Selenium cannot find the path... I added updated Error logs

Comment: Xpath seems to be dynamically generated (so it changes on every execution). That's why Selenium is not finding it. Can you post the HTML around the element you are trying to click?

Comment: I added screen with new xpath which seems to be ok in Chrome and part of HTML. It is steel not working. `div class="sc-bIZIuE bmcBym"` is nested, maybe this cause the problem. From the other hand Crome clearly find the location with the xpath `//div[@class='sc-bIZIuE bmcBym']//small`

Comment: Try using just `//small` as the xpath. If that doesn't work, try using the following css selector: `By.cssSelector("div[class*='Content__ChildWrapper'] small")`.